# How to define '_LIBCPP_VERSION'?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, makefile, tr1

I find some library including codes below:

```
#if defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700)

#define MSGPACK_HAS_STD_UNOURDERED_MAP
#include <unordered_map>
#define MSGPACK_STD_TR1 std

#else   // defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700)

#if __GNUC__ >= 4

#define MSGPACK_HAS_STD_TR1_UNOURDERED_MAP

#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#define MSGPACK_STD_TR1 std::tr1

#endif // __GNUC__ >= 4

#endif  // defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700)
```

I wonder how/where to define `_LIBCPP_VERSION` and `_MSC_VER`, does it auto detect in using default g++?

What if I want to use g++-4.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

`_MSC_VER` is a built-in Visual Studio define. It'll be set to whatever the Visual Studio version is, per [this documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/).

According to [similar documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Libraries/), `_LIBCPP_VERSION` is automatically defined when you include "one of the standard header files". It looks like this is defined when [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/index.html) is being used.

I also see a `__GNUC__` check in your code. That will test for GCC or GCC-compliant compilers, such as Clang.

Let's break your code down line-by-line:

```
#if defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700) //Are we using libc++, or is MSVC installed and above a certain version?

//the next three lines set up defines and includes that libc++/MSVC can use
#define MSGPACK_HAS_STD_UNOURDERED_MAP
#include <unordered_map>
#define MSGPACK_STD_TR1 std

#else   // defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700) //MSVC isn't installed and we're not using libc++, so we'll need to check other compilers

#if __GNUC__ >= 4 //Are we running under GCC or a GCC-compliant compiler?

//the next three lines set up similar defines and includes to the libc++/MSVC ones from above, but these are GCC-based
#define MSGPACK_HAS_STD_TR1_UNOURDERED_MAP
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#define MSGPACK_STD_TR1 std::tr1

#endif // __GNUC__ >= 4 //this ends the GCC test #if block

#endif  // defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) || (_MSC_VER >= 1700) //this ends the libc++/MSVC test #if block
```